# Why is the residual-resistance ratio (RRR) a measure of good crystalline quality?

Tags: electrical-resistance, metals

I am currently revising a paper on a few parameters of metallic Al, and it indicates that a higher RRR is a measure of good crystalline quality. My question is why would this be the case, if having a low ratio (R@300 K / R@4 K) would mean that the resistance is not increasing due to other factors?

Answer (score 1):

At low temperature dislocations etc and impurities are the dominant factors as far as resistance is concerned whereas at higher temperatures lattice vibrations become more important.  So a high resistance ratio means that the low temperature the resistance is comparatively small indicating few dislocations and impurities in the sample.